Energy of moving Sine-Gordon breather
A few days ago I stumbled across the formula for the energy of a moving breather for the sine-Gordon equation
$$ \Box^2 \phi = -\sin\phi.$$ The energy in general is given by ($c=1$)
$$ E = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {1} {2} \left[\left(\frac {\partial \phi} {\partial x}\right)^2+ \left(\frac {\partial \phi} {\partial t}\right)^2\right] +1-\cos\phi \, dx, ~~~~~~~~ (1) $$
and the moving breather solution in question is
$$ \phi(x,t) =4 \arctan\left[\frac {\sqrt{1-w^2}} {w} \frac{\sin\left(w \frac{t-vx} {\sqrt{1-v^2}}\right)} {\cosh\left(\sqrt{1-w^2} \frac {x-vt} {\sqrt{1-v^2}}\right)}\right]. $$
Here, $v$ is the velocity of the breather, and $w$ is a parameter. Now it was claimed in different sources that the energy of this moving breather solution is
$$ E =\frac {E_0} {\sqrt {1 - v^2}}, ~~~~~~~~ (2) $$
where $ E_0 $ is the energy of the resting breather ($v=0$). I did try numerous attempts to derive this formula, by plugging in the breather solution into (1), but always ended up with integrals not even Mathematica was able to solve. I see, that (2) holds for travelling wave solutions $$ \phi(x,t)=\phi\left(\frac {x-vt} {\sqrt{1-v^2}}\right) ,$$ but the breather solution does not have this symmetry. Can anyone provide me a hint on how one can derive (2)? I would very much appreciate it.
Edit: I found for the moving Sine-Gordon breather a direct calculation in this paper: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X17304195 , section 3.
Nevertheless, I'd be very interested in an explicit proof of what Buzz said, that the energy expression (1) (even with a general potential $ V(\phi)$ instead of $1-\cos(\phi$ ) ) indeed transforms as a relativistic four vector when transformed into a frame moving with v, according to the known formulas  $$ E = \gamma (\bar E-v \bar p) ,~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ (3)  $$ $$ p = \gamma (\bar p-\frac{v}{c^2} \bar E),~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ (4) $$
with E given by (1) and p given by $$ p = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}   \frac {\partial \phi} {\partial x}\frac {\partial \phi} {\partial t}  \, dx. ~~~~~~~~ (5) $$
I tried showing this by performing the Lorentz transformation $$ \bar x = \gamma (x-vt), $$ $$ \bar t = \gamma (t-vx), $$ in the energy (1) and ended up with $$ E = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {1} {2} (1+\beta^2)\gamma \left[ \left(\frac {\partial \phi} {\partial \bar x}\right)^2+ \left(\frac {\partial \phi} {\partial \bar t}\right)^2\right] -2 \gamma v \frac {\partial \phi} {\partial \bar x}\frac {\partial \phi} {\partial \bar t} +1-\cos\phi \, d\bar x.  $$
This does obviously not agree with (3), already since the function $\phi(\bar x , \bar t)$ now depends on the position via $\bar t$ , too. What am i missing here?

Which references? Which pages?

The standing breather solution is given by: $\phi(x,t) =4 \arctan\left[\frac {\sqrt{1-w^2}} {w} \frac{\cos\left(w t\right)} {\cosh\left(\sqrt{1-w^2} ,x\right)}\right]$ ;see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine-Gordon_equation

Correction (of wiki): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenkel%E2%80%93Kontorova_model

Since the sine-Gordon theory is $SO(1,1)$ invariant, if you can find the energy for the stationary breather, you can find it for a moving breather as well.  All that is required is a Lorentz boost; note that $E$ is just the energy of a body with rest energy $E_{0}$, boosted by the Lorentz factor $\gamma=(1-v^{2})^{-1/2}$.
If you want to evaluate the integral expression $(1)$ directly, just perform a change of variables to the $(x',t')$ coordinates in which the breather is at rest.  That will take the integral into the special form it takes when $v=0$, multiplied by an overall factor of $\gamma$.
